# Add SQL condition to CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api, criteriaquery

I need add something like Restrictions.sqlRestriction to CriteriaQuery. How to add SQL condition to CriteriaQuery?

My code:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder=entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Installation> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Test.class);
Root<Installation> root = criteriaQuery.from(Test.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA Criteria allows `function()` to be used, or other clauses that have JPQL equivalents. Since you don't say what is the "SQL condition" then that's all that can be said. You certainly can't dump some random SQL into a JPQL filter for example

Comment: I need to use Oracle SQL function 'bitand' for int field

Comment: so use JPA 2.1 "function" keyword, available via CriteriaBuilder, and that way you have no need of "SQL" as such

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it can be done.  I suggest you these 3 options:

- Implement whatever you need to do in your Hibernate entity, but I guess you have already tried and are here looking for some other solution
- Rework your entire query as SQL
- A more creative one: define a new Hibernate entity on a database view doing the 'delicate' part of your query, and leave the rest to be managed via Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my case (call Oracle function 'bitand')

```
   criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(criteriaBuilder.function("bitand", Long.class, root.get(Test_.status).get(Status_.id), criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class, "status")),0));
   TypedQuery<Installation> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery.select(root));
   query.setParameter("status", 1L);
```